# Determine type of set

Tags: computability

Given complement to set $M$ is recursively enumerable and recursive set $R$. What will be the type of the subset of M, elements of which are in R ?

I think they will be also recursively enumerable, but I'm not quite sure about it.

Comment: Both $M$ and $R$ are co-recursively enumerable (meaning the complement of $M$ and the complement of $R$ are r.e.). The intersection of two co-r.e. sets is always co-r.e.

Answer (score -1):

the complement of $M := \Bbb N$ is recursively enumerable; $R := \Bbb N$ is recursive; good luck classifying the subsets of $\Bbb N$.